# MPI to work only on a part of code while the rest is single process

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to figure out how to make `MPI` work in `Fortran` code that only needs the "parallel" job inside `SELECT CASE` statement. My origianal (wrong) idea was to do something like:

```
* some single thread work *
SELECT CASE (i)
CASE (1)
    CALL MPI_INIT (ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)
    IF ( * I am the root process * ) THEN
        * distribute work to the children *
        * do my own load *
    ELSE
        * i am a child *
        * i get some work from the root here *
        * i do my work here *
    END IF
    CALL MPI_BARRIER( MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    CALL MPI_FINALIZE (ierr)
CASE (2)
    * same content as case (1) but a little different work
CASE DEFAULT
    * nothing here *
END SELECT
* some other work for a single thread *
```

But this is wrong, since after `CALL MPI_FINALIZE (ierr)` the other processes do not die as I had expected. The only idea that I have would be to place `STOP` statement at the end of the `ELSE` part which the children do. Will it work? Is there a better way?

Comment: You could look into dynamic process management in MPI. But the most common model for this is to make the standard MPI assumption (all processes running all of the time) and either do the serial work just on rank 0 of MPI_COMM_WORLD, or replicate the work, whichever is most convenient. But I have my suspicions this is an xy problem - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @IanBush I am not sure if I can explain it better. I just want to avoid all processes going through the `select case` part. I want the root to do the decision making. But I am starting to get the feeling that there is no way around it, since `MPI` is just fancy way of starting the process x times and the overheads are unavoidable. The important thing is that once doing there work, there is no interaction between the processes, they just write data to disk and that is it. But I don't want all processes go through everything, it seems very redundant (why should it do the same calc 1000 times?).

Comment: You do not have to do the same calc 1000 times. Compute on one rank and broadcast the result to the other ranks. I would recommend some introduction to how MPI programs typically work. There are many tutorials.

Comment: @VladimirF Would you please provide a reference to some tutorial that actually deals with techniques to write code for MPI? I have found simple ones such as `http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/intro-MPI.shtml` but not much else that has examples. I would like to see some advanced examples of adjusting a serial code (or openmp) for mpi (ideally in fortran) that also has to deal with pre and post parallelization sequence execution and conditionals.

Comment: `if (my_id.eq.0) do_the_work()` so only one task will do the job. if there is no synchronization, then you might not even need MPI. `fork&exec` the slave if you run on one node, or use the resource manager to spawn a slave otherwise.